# Parallel execution on Arduino

Tags: c, parallel-processing, arduino

Lets say I want to control 2 outputs:

One should send a PWM modulated signal (50Hz). The other one should send a audio signal (lets say a sinus-signal) (lets say with 2kHz).

One of those two tasks is simple to do: just run in a loop:

1. send some value to output
2. delay the execution for some ms and jump to 1. again

But how would you solve this problem of sending 2 signals (lets say with different loop frequency, like in our example - 50Hz- 2kHz)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is required to output sinus-signal, but here's my take on a solution. First, what I understand you have:

```
void loop() {
    update_pwm_output();
    delay(1000/50); // 50 Hz
}
```

A possible solution:

```
int last_update = 0;
void loop() {
    int mill = millis();
    if (mill-last_update > (1000/50)) {
        last_update = mill;
        update_pwm_output();
    }
}
```

This solution would allow you to execute other code in between updates to your PWM signal.

There are a couple ways to keep a PWM updated while running other code. A library I've used, [SoftwareServo](http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Servo), allows you to call its `refresh()` method periodically and it'll update, where as the [Servo](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/servo) library takes up a timer and uses an interrupt to do its updates.

Comment: Agreed. The simplest solution is to run your loop as fast as the fastest thing needed, and run the other items based on timers. This avoids using interrupts which add complexity and are a most advanced topic.

Comment: But this is often not possible. Think of classes which need to run their own thing. I guess the thing I am looking for is interrupts.